# PHP PDO file structure

Tags: php, pdo

I know how to use PDO if everything is in one file say index.php. What I want to know if I have three different files one my index.php file the other my functions.php file and the last my database.php file..  How do I use / require the correct files to the correct places.

I have functions in functions.php and it has to have some require/require-once to my database.php (where I connect to database) then in my index.php i want to call that functions?

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php` file you will include, first your `database.php` and after that your `functions.php` file